# How can a child object access the properties of its parent?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two classes: `Message` and `Emailer` with the following (example) properties:

- Message

  - Name
  - EmailAddress
  - Text
  - Email (an instance of Emailer)
- Emailer

  - Send() // this is a method

How can I set this up so that the Emailer instance assigned to Message can access the properties of method? e.g.:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Name;
    public string EmailAddress;
    public string Text;
    public Emailer Email = new Emailer();

    public Message(string name, string emailAddress, string text)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.Text = text;        
    }
}

public class Emailer
{
    public void Send()
    {
        // Send email using Message Properties
    }
}

Message myMessage = new Message('Joe Blow', 'example@email.com', 'Boom Boom Pow');
myMessage.Email.Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchy is wrong.

A `Message` should not own an `Emailer`.  Instead, an `Emailer` should accept a `Message` in its `Send()` method.
To put it differently, an `Emailer` *instance* should not be tied to a single `Message`; instead, it should be able to send as many emails as you want.

---

The actual answer to your question is, you can't.

Instead, you can pass the object as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent-child relationship / inheritance between `Message` and `Emailer` , It is more like composition, where `Message` contains object of `Emailer`. You can't access `Message` properties in `Emailer`.

Your method `Send` in `Emailer` should receive an object of type `Message` and then send email accordingly.

```
public static class Emailer
{
    public static void Send(Message message)
    {
    }
}
```

Your class `Emailer` looks more like a utility class responsible for sending messages. You can declare that as `static` and then use it like:

```
Message myMessage = new Message('Joe Blow', 'example@email.com', 'Boom Boom Pow');
Emailer.Send(myMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're parent;child relationship is backwards.  The message shouldn't need to know anything about the emailer that sends it.  The `Send` method of `Emailer` should be given a `Message` as a parameter:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Name;
    public string EmailAddress;
    public string Text;

    public Message(string name, string emailAddress, string text)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.Text = text;        
    }
}

public class Emailer
{
    public void Send(Message message)
    {
        // Send email using Message Properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the Message object as a parameter in the Emailer constructor:

```
public Emailer Email = new Emailer(this);
```

Then you can have acces to the parent:

```
public class Emailer
{
    private Message _message;

    public Emailer(Message mesage)
{
    _message = message;
}

    public void Send()
    {
        // Send email using Message Properties
        // use _message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct and you wouldn't want to have a Message that owns an Emailer, here's a way that you could do that. I'm providing this simply so you'll understand how a child could know about its parent.

```
public class Message
{
    public string Name;
    public string EmailAddress;
    public string Text;
    public Emailer Email = new Emailer();

    public Message(string name, string emailAddress, string text, Emailer emailer)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.Text = text;
        this.Email= emailer;        
    }
}
```

Then, to create the Message, you'd do this from inside the Emailer:

```
Message mymessage=new Message("John Doe","John.Doe@example.com", "Hello, world!", this);
```

I'm not advocating that you do this, just demonstrating how it could be done for educational purposes.